# A way to reformat and write one pandas dataframe to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes which I would like to join together.

The first data frame (stockData) has more than one stock (the below is just for illustrative purposes) and has the following structure:

```
                           BBG.XLON.VOD.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_VOLUME  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_MKTCAP  
date                                                                           
2001-01-02                  NaN                    NaN                    NaN  
2001-01-03               225.00              444328736            145216.0020  
2001-01-04               239.00              488568000            154251.6643  
2001-01-05               242.25              237936704            156349.2288  
2001-01-08               227.75              658059776            146990.8642  

BBG.XLON.BTA.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_VOLUME  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_MKTCAP  \
date                                                                            
2001-01-02                  572               26605510               37494.60   
2001-01-03                  560               24715470               36708.00   
2001-01-04                  613               52781855               40182.15   
2001-01-05                  630               56600152               41296.50   
2001-01-08                  633               41014402               41493.15
```

and the second data frame (reportingData) again has more data for many different stocks looks like this:

```
           unique_stock_id reporting_type
date                                     
2001-01-03  BBG.XLON.VOD.S         2014:A
2001-01-03  BBG.XLON.VOD.S         2014:S2
2001-01-05  BBG.XLON.BTA.S         2014:A
```

Is there a way to return a resulting dataframe that matches up all the stocks looks like this:

```
            BBG.XLON.VOD.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_VOLUME  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_MKTCAP  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_REPORTING    
date                                                                           
2001-01-02                  NaN                    NaN                    NaN                       NaN    
2001-01-03               225.00              444328736            145216.0020                   2014:S2
2001-01-04               239.00              488568000            154251.6643                       NaN    
2001-01-05               242.25              237936704            156349.2288                       NaN    
2001-01-08               227.75              658059776            146990.8642                       NaN    

            BBG.XLON.BTA.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_VOLUME  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_MKTCAP  BBG.XLON.BTA.S_REPORTING    \
date                                                                            
2001-01-02                  572               26605510               37494.60                       NaN    
2001-01-03                  560               24715470               36708.00                       NaN    
2001-01-04                  613               52781855               40182.15                       NaN    
2001-01-05                  630               56600152               41296.50                    2014:A
```

Comment: how do you choose between `2014:A` and `2014:S2` for the same `date` - what is the algorithm?

Comment: It would matter which one was chosen just as long as one was

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

```
In [316]: df1.join(df2['reporting_type'].groupby(level=0).first())
Out[316]:
            BBG.XLON.VOD.S_LAST  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_VOLUME  BBG.XLON.VOD.S_MKTCAP  \
2001-01-02                  NaN                    NaN                    NaN
2001-01-03               225.00            444328736.0            145216.0020
2001-01-04               239.00            488568000.0            154251.6643
2001-01-05               242.25            237936704.0            156349.2288
2001-01-08               227.75            658059776.0            146990.8642

           reporting_type
2001-01-02            NaN
2001-01-03         2014:A
2001-01-04            NaN
2001-01-05            NaN
2001-01-08            NaN
```

It will first group `df2` by index and will pick up the first value of `reporting_type` for each `date`

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question as my initial attempt at formulating the problem was not quite right.  I have multiple stocks that all need there own 'reporting_type' column.